# Why does material-ui uses large negative relative offset with positive transform?

Tags: material-ui

I noticed that a lot of material-ui elements for example RefreshIndicator have strange style like this:

```
top: -10000px;
left: -10000px;
transform: translate(10010px, 10000px);
```

Can you please explain why do you need this?